# Using Dependency Injection to Configure CookieAuthenticationOptions in AspNetCore Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Is there a way to use Dependency Injection to configure the cookie authentication options? I would like to get some of the settings from the database, but I don't have access to the DatabaseContext at this point.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services
            .AddAuthentication(Authentication.scheme)
            .AddCookie(Authentication.scheme, options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = ".AUTH-Cookie";
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                options.LoginPath = "/Security/SignIn";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Security/SignOut";
                options.EventsType = typeof(CookieAuthenticationEvents);
            });
  ...
}
```

I'm able to use AddOptions() and Configure() to do this with other items in ConfigureServices, but I can't figure out how to do it with the CookieAuthenticationOptions...

```
services
  .AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
  .Configure<IDisplayMetadataProvider>((options, localizationMetadataProvider) =>
  {
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(localizationMetadataProvider);
  });
```

I tried to do the same thing with CookieAuthenticationOptions, but it doesn't appear to work the same way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how to get the data from the database in cookie authentication options,here is a simple sample:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnnectionString")));

    var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var myDbContext = sp.GetService<MyDbContext>();
    var data = GetData(myDbContext);

    services.AddAuthentication(Authentication.scheme)
    .AddCookie(Authentication.scheme,options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = data;
        //...
    });         
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{        
    //be sure you have added authentication middleware
    app.UseAuthentication();

    //if you use asp.net core 3.x,also need to add this
    //app.UseAuthorization();

}
public static string GetData(MyDbContext _context)
{
    //get the data from database
    var data = _context.Tables.Select(j => j.Loginpath).FirstOrDefault();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Is building the service provider multiple times considered an acceptable practice?

Comment: No need to build the service provider multiple times,just use sp.GetService<YourService>() multiple times to get your service.If my answer helped you,could you accept as answer?

Comment: I ended up querying the database directly instead of using the DatabaseContext from the services, but since your answer was a viable, functional route, I'll accept it as the answer. I still wish there was a way to use DI the way you can with AddOptions, but it doesn't appear that it's possible. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

To use Dependency Injection with **CookieAuthenticationOptions** you must call the `AddOptions<>()` and `Configure<>()` methods before calling `AddAuthentication()` or `AddCookie()` authentication handlers.

Here is a sample *DbContext* with a *User* as the user model

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

The code to use dependency injection is below

```
services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions> 
(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .Configure<ApplicationDbContext>(async (options, context) => 
{
    var user = new User
    {
            Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    };
    Console.WriteLine($"------Adding user with DI {user.Id.ToString()}");
    await context.Users.AddAsync(user);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
});
```

When adding **CookieAuthenticationOptions** you must provide the name of the Auth Scheme because it is a named instance. *CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme* defaults to the value of **"Cookies"**. You then can configure these options, and this is where dependency injection kicks in.

You must specify what you want to configure in the **<>**, and this object will be passed into the `Configure()` method along with the named instance of **CookieAuthenticationOptions** that you are configuring.

The anonymous/lambda method is **async** (in this case I use it, but not required) and sends an instance of the options and the specified context into its method.

I create a user using the User class example from above. I create a dummy user to test this and then log the user's id to the console to easily spot it in your logs. I then add the user and save changes to the database and the changes are reflected. This only works/is called when the authentication handler is invoked (ex. logging in/out)

I found this answer based upon these links when attempting to use Redis as my session store and needed Dependency Injection. More Info below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60394756/14465032

[AspNet Core CookieAuthentication with injected SessionStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914143/aspnet-core-cookieauthentication-with-injected-sessionstore)